# APFS Container minimum size equal to current size

Tags: bootcamp, ssd, apfs

I've got a newly installed iMac with a fusion drive consisting of the internal SSD and a secondary SSD which I installed instead of the factory HDD.

I'm now trying to install bootcamp and getting issues with the creation of the new partition.
Bootcamp complains there would not be enough space on the disk.
In fact there is plenty of space available (more then 1.5 TB)

So I checked the minimum size of the APFS Container and the output is as follows:

```
diskutil apfs resizecontainer disk0s2 limits

Resize limits for APFS Physical Store partition disk0s2:
  Current Physical Store partition size on map:   1.9 TB (1920173654016 Bytes)
  Minimum (constrained by file/snapshot usage):   1.9 TB (1920173654016 Bytes)
  Recommended minimum (if used with macOS):       1.9 TB (1920173654016 Bytes)
  Maximum (constrained by partition map space):   1.9 TB (1920173654016 Bytes)
```

As you notice minimum is equal to current.
What's wrong here and how can the values be reset to reasonable settings?

this is the output of

```
david@iMac ~ % diskutil apfs list
APFS Container (1 found)
|
+-- Container disk2 0218B52B-C623-4E1E-95AF-C05AB41E09E5
    ====================================================
    APFS Container Reference:     disk2 (Fusion)
    Size (Capacity Ceiling):      3920362831872 B (3.9 TB)
    Capacity In Use By Volumes:   2015231324160 B (2.0 TB) (51.4% used)
    Capacity Not Allocated:       1905131507712 B (1.9 TB) (48.6% free)
    |
    +-< Physical Store disk0s2 201240FE-3237-4844-AADB-458A59419B57
    |   -----------------------------------------------------------
    |   APFS Physical Store Disk:   disk0s2 (Main, "Faster" Disk Use)
    |   Size:                       1920173654016 B (1.9 TB)
    |
    +-< Physical Store disk1s2 EE4FD562-AB62-447B-9579-00E41DA8AB3B
    |   -----------------------------------------------------------
    |   APFS Physical Store Disk:   disk1s2 (Secondary, Designated Aux Use)
    |   Size:                       2000189177856 B (2.0 TB)
    |
    +-> Volume disk2s1 3C8DE1E2-20FA-484A-8C66-8805A4BED265
    |   ---------------------------------------------------
    |   APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk2s1 (Data)
    |   Name:                      Macintosh HD - Daten (Case-insensitive)
    |   Mount Point:               /System/Volumes/Data
    |   Capacity Consumed:         1992435200000 B (2.0 TB)
    |   FileVault:                 No
    |
    +-> Volume disk2s2 1D17CC7A-A7A7-49C1-A23F-DF7E9689A942
    |   ---------------------------------------------------
    |   APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk2s2 (Preboot)
    |   Name:                      Preboot (Case-insensitive)
    |   Mount Point:               Not Mounted
    |   Capacity Consumed:         85590016 B (85.6 MB)
    |   FileVault:                 No
    |
    +-> Volume disk2s3 E4FFDDDF-447F-445E-B0F3-B7B97B1E7A91
    |   ---------------------------------------------------
    |   APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk2s3 (Recovery)
    |   Name:                      Recovery (Case-insensitive)
    |   Mount Point:               /Volumes/Recovery
    |   Capacity Consumed:         528502784 B (528.5 MB)
    |   FileVault:                 No
    |
    +-> Volume disk2s4 13EB1B45-8528-406C-8828-05A08797617A
    |   ---------------------------------------------------
    |   APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk2s4 (VM)
    |   Name:                      VM (Case-insensitive)
    |   Mount Point:               /private/var/vm
    |   Capacity Consumed:         2148552704 B (2.1 GB)
    |   FileVault:                 No
    |
    +-> Volume disk2s5 19A26984-665C-467B-B75C-56FBB6B4AB8F
        ---------------------------------------------------
        APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk2s5 (System)
        Name:                      Macintosh HD (Case-insensitive)
        Mount Point:               /
        Capacity Consumed:         10946355200 B (10.9 GB)
        FileVault:                 No
```

Comment: I'm not a big bootcamp fan, so I don't use it much, but if I'm not mistaken, the BC partition needs to be outside the APFS container. So, if you APFS container takes up the whole disk, there's no room to create a new partition for BC. What does your APFS container look like?  `diskutil apfs list`

Comment: you are right. the BC partition needs to be outside the apfs container. to create this macos needs to reduce the size of the container to make room for BC but if can not because the minimum size is equal to the maximum size. that would make sense if the disk was full but in fact there is 1.5 TB of space fee.

Comment: What complicates this is that you're using all of it as a fusion drive.  The problem that you're going to have here (I may be mistaken) is that the entire drives (`disk0` and `disk1` are both part of the initial APFS container.  You might have to start from scratch and repartition leaving open a portion of one of the drives.  Is BC a must?  I've found much better results with virtualization.  Also, what about an external Thunderbolt drive partitioned for boot camp?